# Are erlang:send_after/3 and timer:send_after/3 intended to behave differently?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I wanted to send a message to a process after a delay, and discovered `erlang:send_after/4`.

When looking at the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send_after-3) it looked like this is exactly what I wanted:

> `erlang:send_after(Time, Dest, Msg, Options) -> TimerRef`
>
> Starts a timer. When the timer expires, the message Msg is sent to the
>   process identified by Dest.

However, it doesn't seem to work when the destination is running on another node - it tells me one of the arguments are bad.

```
1> P = spawn('node@host', module, function, [Arg]).
<10585.83.0>
2> erlang:send_after(1000, P, {123}).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  erlang:send_after/3
        called as erlang:send_after(1000,<10585.83.0>,{123})
```

Doing the same thing with `timer:send_after/3` appears to work fine:

```
1> P = spawn('node@host', module, function, [Arg]).
<10101.10.0>
2> timer:send_after(1000, P, {123}).
{ok,{-576458842589535,#Ref<0.1843049418.1937244161.31646>}}
```

And, the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#send_after-3) for `timer:send_after/3` state almost the same thing as the `erlang` version:

> `send_after(Time, Pid, Message) -> {ok, TRef} | {error, Reason}`
>
> Evaluates Pid ! Message after Time milliseconds.

So the question is, why do these two functions, which on the face of it do the same thing, behave differently? Is `erlang:send_after` broken, or mis-advertised? Or maybe `timer:send_after` isn't doing what I think it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR

Your assumption is correct: these are intended to do the same thing, but are implemented differently.

## Discussion

Things in the `timer` module such as `timer:send_after/2,3` work through the gen_server that defines that as a service. Like any other service, this one can get overloaded if you assign a really *huge* number of tasks (timers to track) to it.

`erlang:send_after/3,4`, on the other hand, is a BIF implemented directly within the runtime and therefore have access to system primitives like the hardware timer. If you have a ton of timers this is definitely the way to go. In *most* programs you won't notice the difference, though.

There is actually a note about this in the [Erlang Efficiency Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/commoncaveats.html#id65681):

> 3.1  Timer Module
>
> Creating timers using erlang:send_after/3 and erlang:start_timer/3 , is much more efficient than using the timers provided by the timer module in STDLIB. The timer module uses a separate process to manage the timers. That process can easily become overloaded if many processes create and cancel timers frequently (especially when using the SMP emulator).
>
> The functions in the timer module that do not manage timers (such as timer:tc/3 or timer:sleep/1), do not call the timer-server process and are therefore harmless.

### A workaround

A workaround to gain the efficiency of the BIF without the same-node restriction is to have a process of your own that does nothing but wait for a message to forward to another node:

```
-module(foo_forward).
-export([send_after/3, cancel/1]).
% Obviously this is an example only. You would want to write this to
% be compliant with proc_lib, write a proper init/N and integrate with
% OTP. Note that this snippet is missing the OTP service functions.

start() ->
    spawn(fun() -> loop(self(), [], none) end).

send_after(Time, Dest, Message) ->
    erlang:send_after(Time, self(), {forward, Dest, Message}).

loop(Parent, Debug, State) ->
    receive
        {forward, Dest, Message} ->
            Dest ! Message,
            loop(Parent, Debug, State);
        {system, From, Request} ->
            sys:handle_msg(Request, From, Parent, ?MODULE, Debug, State);
        Unexpected ->
            ok = log(warning, "Received message: ~tp", [Unexpected]),
            loop(Parent, Debug, State)
    end.
```

The above example is a bit shallow, but hopefully it expresses the point. It should be possible to get the efficiency of the BIF `erlang:send_after/3,4` but still manage to send messages across nodes as well as give you the freedom to cancel a message using `erlang:cancel_timer/1`

### But why?

The puzzle (and bug) is why `erlang:send_after/3,4` does not want to work across nodes. The example you provided above looks a bit odd as the first assignment to `P` was the Pid `<10101.10.0>`, but the crashed call was reported as `<10585.83.0>` -- clearly not the same.

For the moment I do not know *why* `erlang:send_after/3,4` doesn't work, but I can say with confidence that the mechanism of operation between the two is not the same. I'll look into it, but I imagine that the BIF version is actually doing some funny business within the runtime to gain efficiency and as a result signalling the target process by *directly updating its mailbox* instead of actually sending an Erlang message on the higher Erlang-to-Erlang level.

Maybe it is good that we have both, but *this should definitely be clearly marked in the docs*, and it evidently is not (I just checked).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the example looks a bit odd! This is because I edited it somewhat. This two pids are actually the same in the shell - sorry!

Answer (score 1):

There is some difference in timeout order if you have many timers.
The example below shows *erlang:send_after* does not guarantee order, but
*timer:send_after* does.

```
1> A = lists:seq(1,10).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2> [erlang:send_after(100, self(), X) || X <- A].
...
3> flush().
Shell got 2
Shell got 3
Shell got 4
Shell got 5
Shell got 6
Shell got 7
Shell got 8
Shell got 9
Shell got 10
Shell got 1
ok
4> [timer:send_after(100, self(), X) || X <- A]. 
...
5> flush().
Shell got 1
Shell got 2
Shell got 3
Shell got 4
Shell got 5
Shell got 6
Shell got 7
Shell got 8
Shell got 9
Shell got 10
ok
```